# strange error using AttrDict on Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am getting a weird recurring error using **AttrDict** 2.0 on Python 2.7.  The weird part is that transitive assignment seems to break, but only when using AttrDict.

What's happening is that I want to instantiate a new list on an object if it doesn't exist and then append data to it.

If I use AttrDict, the list somehow gets transformed into a tuple and I get an exception.

```
from attrdict import AttrDict

class Test(object):
    pass

try:

    for cls_ in [Test,AttrDict]:
        foo = cls_()        
        print ("\ntesting with class %s" % (cls_))

        #this 
        chk = foo.li = getattr(foo, "li", None) or []
        print("  type(chk):%s, id(chk):%s" % (type(chk),id(chk)))
        print("  type(foo.li):%s, id(foo.li):%s" % (type(foo.li),id(foo.li)))
        foo.li.append(3)
        print ("  success appending with class %s: foo.li:%s" % (cls_, foo.li))

except (Exception,) as e:
    # pdb.set_trace()
    raise
```

Now check out the output, when I use the `Test` class vs when I use `AttrDict`.

```
testing with class <class '__main__.Test'>
  type(chk):<type 'list'>, id(chk):4465207704
  type(foo.li):<type 'list'>, id(foo.li):4465207704
  success appending with class <class '__main__.Test'>: foo.li:[3]
```

With the custom `Test` class, as expected, `chk` and `foo.li` are both lists and have the same `id`.  append works.

Looking at the pass using AttrDict, `id` does not match and `foo.li` is a tuple rather than a list.

```
testing with class <class 'attrdict.dictionary.AttrDict'>
  type(chk):<type 'list'>, id(chk):4465207848
  type(foo.li):<type 'tuple'>, id(foo.li):4464595080
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_attrdict2.py", line 25, in <module>
    test()
  File "test_attrdict2.py", line 18, in test
    foo.li.append(3)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Is attrdict assignment actually returning some kind of property/accessor object that gets changed the 2nd time you access it?

Took @abartnet's suggestion:

```
from attrdict import AttrDict
a = AttrDict()
a.li = [] 
print(a.li)
```

output: 
`()`

OK, but even if that points to some weird behavior on AttrDict's end, how is it the transitive assignment does not assign the tuple as well?

reworked:

```
from attrdict import AttrDict
a = AttrDict()
b = a.li = [] 
print("a.li:", a.li)    
print("b:",b)
```

output:

```
('a.li:', ())
('b:', [])
```

Comment: You should be able to test this without all this other stuff in the way: What happens if you just do `a = AttrDict(); a.li = []; print(a.li)`? Is it `[]` or `()`? If it's the latter, everything else in your question is irrelevant.

Comment: I only added the chk to try to debug, it was breaking before.  The test class was there to make sure I wasn't somehow messing up the attribute initialization, and it seems to point to an issue with AttrDict.  But, yes, I will add your suggestion.

Comment: This seems to be intended behavior of `AttrDict`, even if it's not explained that well in the README.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of the automatic recursiveness of `AttrDict`. Which is explained better in the inline `help` (which you can find [here](https://github.com/bcj/AttrDict/blob/master/attrdict/mixins.py#L16) in the source) than in the README:

> If a values which is accessed as an attribute is a Sequence-type (and is not a string/bytes), it will be converted to a _sequence_type with any mappings within it converted to Attrs.

In other words, in order to auto-convert any `dict` or other mappings recursively inside your `AttrDict` to `AttrDict` values when doing attribute access, it also converts all sequences to (by default) `tuple`. This is a little weird, but appears to be intentional and somewhat-documented behavior, not a bug.

```
>>> a = AttrDict()
>>> a._sequence_type
tuple
>>> a.li = []
>>> a.li
()
```

---

The more flexible `AttrMap` type lets you specify the sequence type, and documents that you can disable this recursive remapping stuff by passing `None`:

```
>>> a = AttrMap(sequence_type=None)
>>> a.li = []
>>> a.li
[]
```

But of course `AttrMap` isn't a `dict` (although it is a `collections.abc.MutableMapping`, and more generally it duck-types as a `dict`-like type).

---

> OK, but even if that points to some weird behavior on AttrDict's end, how is it the transitive assignment does not assign the tuple as well?

Because that's not how chained assignment works. Oversimplifying a bit:

```
target1 = target2 = value
```

… is not equivalent to this:

```
target2 = value
target1 = target2
```

… but to this:

```
target2 = value
target1 = value
```

The best way to understand why that's true: targets aren't expressions, and therefore don't have values. Sure, often the exact same sequence of tokens *would* be valid as an expression elsewhere in the grammar, but that sequence of tokens never gets evaluated as an expression anywhere in an assignment statement—otherwise, simple things like `d['spam'] = 'eggs'` would have to raise an exception if `d['spam']` didn't exist.

Also, `a.li = []` doesn't actually assign `tuple([])` anywhere; it actually stores the `[]` internally, and does the `tuple(…)` later, when you try to access `a.li`. You can't really tell that for sure without reading the source, but when you consider that `a['li']` gives you `[]` rather than `()`, it pretty much has to be true. And, in fact:

```
>>> li = []
>>> a.li = li
>>> a['li'] is li
True
```

Comment: so, each target in the transitive assignment gets the list.  AttrDict transforms it into a tuple, but that is it's business and does not affect the assignment to `chk`/`b` in my example?  makes sense.

Comment: @JLPeyret Exactly. In fact, if you read through the source, `AttrDict` doesn't even transform it into a tuple _now_, but only _later_, when you access it via `a.li`. That's why `a['li']` can still work.